# Unable to find the right excel file library reference error

Tags: excel, vba

Every time I open this Excel file I get this error which is in screenshot 1 and screenshot 2.

When I click OK it takes me to code windows and asks me to select library.

I tried everything to make it work but no luck.

Screenshot one and screenshot two:
[image]

Comment: The code adds a reference to the  `Microsoft HTML Object Library` which is described in a file `mshtml.tlb`. This file `mshtml.tlb` is not found at your machine. So this seems to be a misconfiguration of your machine.

Comment: try, while in VBE, to click Tools -> References, scroll the listbox till "Microsoft HTML Object Library" entry, tick its checkmark and click Ok

Comment: @user3598756: I suspect this is already done as the first error states. I suspect someone has tried to "Remove Internet Explorer From Windows" and has ignored the message that this "might affect other Windows features and programs installed on your computer, including default settings".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Make sure that these references are in this Priority order.

HTML and Internet Controls need to be above OLE Automation.

If you are still having this issue after this, run a Repair on the Office install and it refreshes the .DLL files that may have been corrupted.

Update: 7/6/2017

The pervious answer above will re-associate the references and allow the script to compile.

However, there is a better way.

This issue occurs when the VBA script is shared to other computers that are not identical platforms(OS and MS Office versions) and use early binding. Early binding reduces latency and is the correct way when only intended for one computer.

The answer is to use late binding format in the script and not select any references. Change any data type objects other than object back to object and use the following format:

```
Sub Late_Binding()  
Dim IE_App_obj As Object
Dim MyShell_obj As Object
Dim IE_Window_obj As Object
Dim Windows_cnt As Long
Dim x_cnt As Variant
Dim HTML_Element_obj As Object

Set IE_App_obj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'Use IE_App_obj to Navigate to webpage and control it.'

Set MyShell_obj = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
'Use MyShell_obj to find an existing webpage and control it.'

Let Windows_cnt = MyShell.Windows.Count

For x_cnt = Windows_cnt - 1 To 0 Step -1
    On Error Resume Next
    If Instr(MyShell_obj.Windows(x_cnt).Document.Title,"WebPage_Title") > 0 Then
       Set IE_Window_obj = MyShell_obj.Windows(x_cnt)
       Exit For
    End If
Next

Set HTML_Element_obj = IE_Window_obj.Document.getElementByID("ID_text")



End Sub
```

Latency will increase but so will stability.

Comment: Why would HTML and Internet Controls need to be above OLE Automation?  That doesn't make any sense - the reference priority determines *binding order* for libraries - ***not*** whether individual library members are bindable.